# Thickness of horizontal ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-view, android-progressbar

I want to implement a thick horizontal progress bar, however I can't manage to get it thick. I tried `android:minHeight="300dp"`, but that did not help. Bar is still thin.

Here is the extract from my XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/server_top_left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/config"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text=" Config "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/control"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/config"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text=" Control "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/control"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:progress="79" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:progress="50" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One of the bars has width=wrap_content, the other has fixed width to 300dp, both look the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your custom progressbar style.
You can modify progress_horizontal.xml by changing radius attribute
or you can modify progress_horizontal_holo.xml by changing drawables.